# Validação para evitar registro duplicados em um formulário PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, banco-de-dados

Estou com um site aonde o usuário insere: -Código Produto `codProd` , Descrição Produto `descProd` e Unidade de Medida `unidMed`. Nesse caso queria colocar um tipo de mensagem printada na tela, se o usuário digitasse um Código de Produto que já estivesse cadastrado (pra ajudar coloquei `codProd` como chave primária no banco).

```
<form action="produto.php" id='cadastroRegistro' method = "POST">
      <div class='label'>
          <div>Código do Produto:</div>
            <div>
              <input id='nome' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="16" name = 'codProd'/>
            </div>
      </div>

          

      <div class='label'>
          <div>Descrição do Produto:</div>
            <div>
              <input type='text' id='fone' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="50" name = 'descProd'/>
            </div>
      
      </div>
      <div class='label'>
          <div>Unidade de Medida:</div>
            <div>
            <select name="select_unidMed" required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecione</option>
                    <?php
                        $select_unidMed2 = "SELECT * FROM UnidMed";
                        $select_unidMed2 = mysqli_query($conexao, $select_unidMed2);
                        while($row_unidMed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_unidMed2)){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_unidMed['codUnidMed']; ?>" <?php
                     if($select_unidMed == $row_unidMed['codUnidMed']){
                         echo 'selected';
                     }
                     ?>
              >
              
              
              <?php echo $row_unidMed['codUnidMed']; ?></option> <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
      
      </div>
```

Parte PHP do formulário

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $idProd = $_POST['idProd'];
  $codProd = $_POST['codProd'];
  $descProd = $_POST['descProd'];
  $select_unidMed = $_POST['select_unidMed'];

  $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO Produto(idProd,codProd,descProd,codUnidMed) VALUES('$idProd', '$codProd', '$descProd', '$select_unidMed')");
  


}


$validacao = "SELECT codProd FROM Produto where codProd = '$codProd'";

$duperaw = mysqli_query($conexao, $validacao);

if (mysqli_num_rows($duperaw) > 0) {
  echo $validacao;

  
}

else {
// continui //
}
```

Comment: Você precisa realizar a validação antes de fazer a inserção.

Answer (score -2):

Dá para você usar o `$_SESSION` para mostrar essa mensagem de duplicidade.

**Exemplo PHP**

```
$validacao = "SELECT codProd FROM Produto WHERE codProd = '$codProd'"
$duperaw = mysqli_query($conexao, $validacao);

if(mysqli_num_rows($duperaw) > 0){
    $_SESSION['duplicado'] = true;
    echo "<script> window.location.href='endereco.php'</script>";
    exit();
}
```

**Página HTML**
No lugar que você desejar mostrar a mensagem de erro você verifica a sessão.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['duplicado'])){
?>

   <span>Mensagem de erro</span>

<?php
}
unset($_SESSION['duplicado'])
?>
```

Não esqueça de dar um `session_start();` no começo dos dois arquivos, ou irá dar erros pois nenhuma sessão foi iniciada.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).